# Type variable ... is unbound (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, mypy, typing

I've realised that the following works as long as the TypeVar statement is in the same module as where it is applied:

```
import pathlib
PathLike = TypeVar("PathLike", str, pathlib.Path)
```

However, when I move the TypeVar statement to another module - say customtypes - and I only use PathLike to indicate the type of the variable holding the path to my file, then this happens:

```
fn: PathLike
```

Mypy: Type variable "customtypes.PathLike" is unbound
(Hint: Use "Generic[PathLike]" or "Protocol[PathLike]" base class to bind "PathLike" inside a class)
(Hint: Use "PathLike" in function signature to bind "PathLike" inside a function). I'm not using "PathLike" within a class or function. I'm not getting the hints in the first place. I don't understand the use of the keyword Generic.

Furthermore, typing is not able to handle the following:

```
import array
from typing import NewType, TypeVar
try:
    import numpy as np
    ArrayLike = TypeVar("ArrayLike", array.array, np.ndarray)
except ImportError:
    ArrayLike = NewType("ArrayLike", array.array)
```

The error is: Mypy: Cannot redefine "ArrayLike" as a NewType
Name "ArrayLike" already defined on line 5

When I try to add the definition of ArrayLike to my module customtypes, things seem to go wrong. In the module where I try to then use the new types I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
from customtypes import PathLike, ArrayLike 
df = pd.read_csv(fn)
result = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    arr: ArrayLike = row.to_numpy(dtype="float32")
    result.append(arr)
```

Mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ndarray[Any, Any]", variable has type "array[Any]"). I guess that MyPy is programmed to assume that ndarray is a multidimensional array. How can I indicate to MyPy that ndarray is a flat array?

Comment: Have you tried reading PEP484 explanation of type variables and generics first? Seems like both your `TypeVar` and `NewType` approaches do not do what you expect. https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics

Comment: The definition of `ArrayLike` must be able to be determined without runtime effects like trying to import `numpy`.